# ipython notebook read multiple images and display in CELL

Tags: ipython, display

How do I do the above ? This is my code but it doesn't work nothing is displayed

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('<my directory>.pgm'):
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(10):
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(image_list[i])
```

I would like it to be displayed in the cell

Comment: Can you add plt.show() after plt.imshow(image_list[]) inside the loop ?

Comment: Hi thanks. I have but the images are not displayed in a cell i.e. new windows is created for the images.

Comment: you should add :  "%matplotlib inline" before your code above

Comment: cool i added my comment as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you should add `%matplotlib inline`before your code and make sure that after plt.imshow(images_list) you add plt.show() as well so matplotlib renders your images.

Answer (score 7):

If you're interested in a much simpler and faster way of displaying images I recommend [IPyPlot package](https://github.com/karolzak/ipyplot):

```py
import ipyplot

ipyplot.plot_images(images_list, max_images=20, img_width=150)
```

It's capable of displaying hundreds of images in a grid-like format within just 60-70ms

You would get a plot similar to this:
[image]

Comment: how can i delete the link above each figure?

Comment: there's a param called `show_url` which you can set to `False` like this:
`ipyplot.plot_images(images_list, max_images=20, img_width=150, show_url=False)`